# Node.js cors req.headers.cookie?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express, http-headers

I have a node.js server that handles some stuff, it sits on port `:9000`, I built an authentication middleware to restrict some routes.

I am not able to get the cookie though, so I suspect it is because the `req` is coming from another place `:3000` for example.

I am not trying to get the cookie express sets, I am trying to get a client side PHP cookie from the `req`

```
// using var req = http.IncomingMessage.prototype;
req.authenticated = function(callback) {
    console.log(this.headers.cookie)
}
```

So the question is how can I setup so that whenever `:3000` makes a request to my node.js server `:9000` the cookie is sent with the headers?

Comment: The browser stores a separate set of cookies for each origin.  You can't (easily) do that.

Comment: What are my options?

Comment: You should put everything on one server.  (or learn about SSO techniques)

Comment: Really? there has to be a way.

Comment: We cant really do that, the core app is built on symfony, but I built a node server for real time chatting.

Comment: When I make a request cant I just use

xhrFields:
    withCredentials: true https://quickleft.com/blog/cookies-with-my-cors/

Comment: No; that's the opposite problem (passing _the other authority's_ cookies to itself)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a number of options:

- You can put both servers behind a reverse proxy (such as nginx) and map different URLs from the same authority to different backends.
- You could configure Apache (or whatever server your main site is hosted on) to forward some URLs to your Node server using mod_proxy ([instructions](http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache/))
- You could host your Node server on a subdomain of the main server, and use the same port, then use domain-wildcard cookies
- You could send the auth token explicitly as an HTTP header set by your client code (you'll need to send the raw auth token to the client accessible via JS; beware of XSS attacks)
- You could have the main site send a signed request to a URL on the Node.js server to set an auth cookie on its authority (you'll need to do the same on logout, and to prevent CSRF, session fixing, and other attacks; learn about SSO techniques)